# How to break JQuery statements down into simpler to read statements?

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and was experimenting with breaking the code down so that I could see how it works better. I cam up with this type of code. Is there a better way to break this down so that a person can see what all it does. What I have seen of JQuery it is a bit tidies to look at because to me it seems to get real complete really quick. I think that the variable could just be function names called inside of each other as well. It did not work when I made them functions and tried to call them as a() and t().

****Question: What is the best way to break down JQuery so that a person can see how it works better?****

```
var a = function() 
        {
         $(this).hide();
        };

var t = function()
        {
         $("p").click(a);
        };

$(document).ready(t);
```

Code Here:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

<script>

var a = function() 
        {
         $(this).hide();
        };

var t = function()
        {
         $("p").click(a);
        };

$(document).ready(t);

</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the "hard" thing to read is not using meaningful names (or truly anonymous functions), relevant scoping, or common idioms. However, those statements are so simple already that I would expect any developer (given familiarization with HTML+JS/jQuery) to be able to grasp their intent, even when written in such a convoluted "simple" form.

Comment: This is for learning I do not think that someone would probably do this in a real page.

Comment: Learn as it *would* be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than try and break it down to lines why not just comment your code? Comments can leave valuable feedback so that developers yourself included can remember what a segment of code is trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //Wait until the entire document has loaded, then execute the code in this function
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Setup a listener for when ever a <p> is clicked
                $('p').on('click',function(event){
                    //Execute this code when the <p> is clicked
                    $(this).hide(); // This will hide the <p> that was clicked
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>A</p>
        <p>B</p>
        <p>C</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most of those comments are already duplicated by the (amazing!) meaningfully picked function names and consistent jQuery behavior. But I do agree - this way of writing it, even without comments, is quite simply less convoluted and more idiomatic than the posted form.

Comment: why yes they are, but my example is more to show to use comments not really to use THESE comments. You can add comments to explain intent of the code.

Comment: I am not just a fan of anonymous functions. I just want to break them apart so that I can see how they work. It is more for learning than real life.    $('p').on('click',function(event){...etc...} is even different than it was on the example that I had found on the internet. So there is more than one way to do they same thing.

Comment: @user3376708 A problem with the "simple" code is that the *names are terrible* which makes it harder to read and comprehend.

Comment: @user3376708 The on function is the latest recommended way of handling adding event listeners using jquery. Previously all of the event listeners had their own functions, like `.click`, `.hover` but now they have wrapped it into 1 function and you just pass the event to listen for and the event handler